# Copy-item with File-Out parameter

Tags: powershell, file-io, output

```
Copy-item -Force -Verbose -Recurse $sourceDirectory -Destination $destinationDirectory |
Out-File -FilePath D:\victor.txt
```

I do not know why it doesn't copy the output of the PowerShell to the text file. Will appreciate if someone can help thanks!!

Comment: Add `-PassThru` switch --> `Copy-item -Force -Verbose -Recurse $sourceDirectory -Destination $destinationDirectory -PassThru | Out-File -FilePath D:\victor.txt
`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to capture all output and redirect it to a file:

```
Copy-item -Force -Verbose -Recurse $sourceDirectory -Destination $destinationDirectory *> D:\victor.txt

*   All output  
1   Success output  
2   Errors  
3   Warning messages  
4   Verbose output  
5   Debug messages
```